# Conversion stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()) from Swift2 to Swift3

Tags: swift, string, swift2, swift3, ios10

I'm trying to convert the following line of code from **Swift 2** to **Swift 3** while upgrading my program but I can't figure out what the equivalent is for Swift 3?

```
guard let password = passwordField.text!.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()) , !password.isEmpty else {
                    displayErrorMessage(errorMessage: "Password can not be empty!")
                    return false
                }
```

**The error I get is:**

> ****Value of type 'String' has no member 'stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters'****

Comment: Linked page also has answers for Swift 3.

Comment: ah thanks let me try that out didn't realize already an answer.